# I have to calculate the following integral: $\int \lvert\sin(k\cdot x)\rvert\, \mathrm{d}x,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to calculate the following integral: $$\int_0^\pi \lvert\sin(k\cdot x)\rvert\, \mathrm{d}x,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
What I've tried, but is undoubtedly wrong:

> [image]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please use MathJax for to write your problem. Also, it's important that you show your attempts  for to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^\pi |\sin k x| dx = k \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{k}} \sin k x \, dx = k \cdot \frac{2}{k} =2, \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}).$$

Similarly for $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{<0}$,$$\int_0^\pi |\sin k x| dx =2.$$

Of course $k=0$ requires special treatment:

$$\int_0^\pi |\sin k x| dx =0, \quad \text{when } k=0.$$

**UPDATE**

To evaluate the integral:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{k}} \sin k x dx = \left.\frac{1}{k} \cos kx\right|_{\frac{\pi}{k}}^0=\frac{1}{k}(1-(-1))=\frac{2}{k}.$$

Comment: Can you explain why you're able to "ignore" the abs value function?

Comment: Because in the interval $[0,\pi]$ the sine is always positive.

Comment: The function $|\sin k x|$ is periodic with period $\pi/k$.  Over the first period $|\sin k x|=\sin k x$.

Comment: do you mean in the interval [0,pi/k] or [0,pi]?

Comment: I'm pretty new to integrals, and I've never seen a change of the upper bound of the integral so yeah, I dont quite understand it...

Comment: $\int_0^\pi = \int_0^{\pi/k} + \int_{\pi/k}^{2\pi/k} + \cdots + \int_{\pi - \pi/k}^\pi$

Comment: Note that $\pi/k$ is in the interval $[0,\pi]$ if $k$ is positive.

Comment: Break the integral up over these smaller intervals, and by periodicity, they are all equal and thus equal to the integral over the first interval where $|\sin kx| = \sin kx$.

Comment: got it! thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: mow could you also write the antiderivative because allthough I understand it im getting a different result...

Comment: Sure, please see the updated answer.